# timer_create and TimerQueueTimer functionality in portable library (like boost)

Tags: c++, boost, timer, portability

I have written a program that runs on Linux and uses sigevent and timer_create in order to have a callback function being called perdiodically at a specified frequency. Now, I want the program to be portable (Windows and Linux), so the long way to do it is to use #ifdefs and use Windows equivalent functionality.

AFAIK, the equivalent on windows would be TimerQueueTimer.

I know this is a OS service, but just like thread, it can be made portable via a library like Boost C++.

The question is: do you know if there is such things in the Boost C++ library, or maybe in POCO or other respectable library?

If it is absent, then is there anything preventing the presence of such thing in a portable library?

FYI, boost::asio::deadline_timer is not what I am looking for, it must be a service that calls periodically a callback function with the same precision as timer_create and TimerQueueTimer.

Comment: At first I thought libev might solve your problem, but then I realized I never heard of it running on Windows, so after a litter research I found this: http://doc.dvgu.ru/devel/ev.html#win32_platform_limitations_and_workarounds

Well, according to them, Windows event system is too different from POSIX to be compatible...

Comment: You need to use a portable library for that. Take another look at `boost::asio`, it can certainly do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[POCO](http://pocoproject.org/docs/) has a multi-threaded Timer class that runs TimerTask(s).  Basically you override a TimerTask's run() method with what you want to do when the timer expires.  Multiple tasks can be added to the Timer object which spawns a thread to sequentially run all pending tasks.  The tasks can be one-time or interval repeatable.

Not sure if it meets all of your needs but it is worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend ACE (The Adaptive Communications Environment). Specifically look into the ACE_Reactor class and the ACE_Reactor::schedule_timer(...) method.

[Visit the Wiki page for more general information about ACE.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Communication_Environment)

[Or go directly to the official website.](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html)